# Angular2: appending a component to body removes your ability to destroy it via ComponentRef

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm looking for the optimal way to get around the following situation:

We have a modal that is appended to body via the `document.body.appendChild` method.

We do this for accessibility reasons.

We create this modal with via `ViewContainerRef` and `ComponentFactory`.

So long as we don't append the component to body we can call the destroy method on the componentRef and remove the component from the screen all together. However since we have to append the element to body, calling `componentRef.destroy()` succeeds with no error and leaves the component on the screen.

For now we are going to use `document.body.removeChild`. Is there a better way around this? Why does this happen? Would using `Renderer2` (later down the road post hopeful upgrade) help angular maintain control of this object and successfully remove it from the dom?

Comment: maybe it´s worth to look into Angular CDK Portals: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-cdk-portals-b02f66dd020c